# Twilio TaskRouter - Controlling the order which TaskQueue selects Workers

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Ahoy! First time TaskRouter user here. I have about 500 Workers which meet the `TargetWorkers` expression for my TaskQueue. I also have a priority for each Worker, where this priority is any integer.

Ideally: I'd like Tasks to be assigned to my Workers based on the Worker's priority. Doesn't need to be exactly like this, but that's my ideal. Any ideas on how to build this out in Twilio TaskRouter?

Example: Given two available Workers `A` and `B`, where `A` has high priority (1025) and `B` has lower priority (2). I want the incoming task to be assigned to `A` whenever possible. The task should only go to Worker `B` if Worker `A` is not available, times out, or rejects the offer.

Is there documentation somewhere which explains the order in which  TaskQueues select between available workers?